# make a link that when clicked disappear and show a div instead

Tags: javascript, html

How would I use javascript to make a link that, when clicked, disappears and in its place a hidden div appears?

I am hoping for something like this:

```
[link]
<div id="hidden" style="hidden">
//hidden content
</div>
```

and when you click the link the div turns to "style='show'" and the link disappears.

I hope this makes sense...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In simple terms wihout using libraries:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="this.style.display = 'none'; document.getElementById('hidden').style.display = 'block'">Click me</a>
<div id="hidden" style="display: none">...</div>
```